# Bash Script to take the timestamp of a logged files and subtract it from the timestamp of another log file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am trying to write a script that will have the following information:

```
   4824597 11:26 /home/customer1/ITAM.xml
   .
   .
   .
   .
   4824597 14:08 /home/customer46/ecds/dropoff/ITAM.xml
```

I have another file that will log the same information

```
   4824597 11:28 /home/customer1/ITAM.xml
   .
   .
   .
   .
   4824597 14:11 /home/customer46/ecds/dropoff/ITAM.xml
```

I want see how long it takes to receive files. To do this I want to subtract the timestamp of all the files logged in the log, and subtract them from their initial timestamp in the first log file.

I am new to scripting and am struggling to make this work.  I am trying:

```
   #!/bin/bash
   time=$11:48:30
   day=$2012-10-12
   time2=$13:13:48
   t=$(date -d "day time" +%s)
   t1=$(date -d "day time2" +%s)
   diff=$(expr $t1 - $t)
   echo $diff
```

So far no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also is it possible to get a timestamp in the log file that will goto seconds?  Right now I have 

timestamp=$(du --time-style=full-iso "$THIS_FILE" | cut -f 2)

Comment: if you have the `stat` command-line utility available (I think most linuxes do) you can get the file modification time in seconds since the epoch with `stat -c %Y filename`.  See `man 1 stat` for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
awk '{
  sub(/:/," ",$2);
  t1=mktime(strftime("%Y %m %d")" "$2" 00");
  getline < "input2.txt";
  sub(/:/," ",$2);
  t2=mktime(strftime("%Y %m %d")" "$2" 00");
  print $3": "t2-t1" s"
}' input1.txt
```

Comment: So here the "input*.txt files are they the log files?

Comment: hey when I run the command on files I've sent I get a strange output -7190560 s; is the command supposed to output in seconds?

Comment: @user2019182 Yes. Also, it's assuming that `11:26` has the format `hh:mm`. If the format is `mm:ss` you need to change `" "$2" 00"` to `" 00 "$2`.

Comment: ok it is set to hh:mm so I wasn't sure it that was actually referencing milliseconds becuase that would make sense, or if its converting the time to seconds from 1970.